# RadioButton как вычислить значение

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, radiobutton

При вводе аргумента x и нажатии Button  проверяется в какой из трех диапазонов
попадает x, выполняются вычисления и результат отображается в TextView.
При этом соответствующая радиокнопка становится отмеченной.
Если далее  нажать другую радиокнопку,  вычисления пересчитываются для формулы, соответствующей этой кнопки, в TextView выводится новый результат, диапазон, в котором  находится x игнорируется.
Проблема в том, что при нажатии на другую радиокнопку, она все равно считает по формуле, в которое попадает значение X. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать

Код программы

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test
      import android.os.Bundle
      import android.widget.Button
      import android.widget.Button
      import android.widget.CheckBox
      import android.widget.EditText
      import android.widget.RadioButton
      import android.widget.TextView
      import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
      import kotlin.math.pow
      import kotlin.math.sin
      import kotlin.math.sqrt
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var editTextX: EditText
private lateinit var buttonCalculate: Button
private lateinit var textViewResult: TextView
private lateinit var radioButtonFormula1: RadioButton
private lateinit var radioButtonFormula2: RadioButton
private lateinit var radioButtonFormula3: RadioButton
private lateinit var checkBoxDouble: CheckBox

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    editTextX = findViewById(R.id.editTextX)
    buttonCalculate = findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate)
    textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textViewResult)
    radioButtonFormula1 = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFormula1)
    radioButtonFormula2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFormula2)
    radioButtonFormula3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButtonFormula3)
    checkBoxDouble = findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDouble)

    buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener {
        calculateResult()
    }

    // Начальная установка радиокнопок
    radioButtonFormula1.isChecked = false
}

private fun calculateResult() {
    val x = editTextX.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()

    if (x != null) {
        val result = when {
            x <= 2 -> {
                radioButtonFormula1.isChecked = true
                sin(x + 1)
            }
            x > 2 && x < 3 -> {
                radioButtonFormula2.isChecked = true
                sqrt(x.pow(3) - 1)
            }
            else -> {
                radioButtonFormula3.isChecked = true
                x + 1.5
            }
        }

        if (checkBoxDouble.isChecked) {
            textViewResult.text = (result * 2).toString()
        } else {
            textViewResult.text = result.toString()
        }
    } else {
        textViewResult.text = "Введите корректное значение x"
    }
} }
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="100dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCalculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/checkBoxDouble"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:text="Вычислить" />


<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxDouble"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
    android:text="Удвоить результат" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextX"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:hint="Введите значение x"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/buttonCalculate"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonFormula1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Формула 1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonFormula2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Формула 2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonFormula3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Формула 3" />
</RadioGroup> </RelativeLayout>
```